# Why is the password set to null in JSON data?

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson

I have a strange situation with Spring Boot 2.7.7 and need some guidance how to troubleshoot.

Here is an `Account` entity and for security reasons I hide the password field.

```java
@Entity
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class Account extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
...

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
}
```

On the frontend side (ReactJS) I don't see the password field, so the above annotation works.

After I try to change an attribute value of the account on the frontend side, e.g. title, the password is reset to `null`.

Here is the update service:

```java
@Autowired
private IAccountRepository accountRepository;

public Account updateAccount(Long id, Account account) throws CustomException {
   return accountRepository.save(account);
}
```

Why is this happening? And how could I ensure that the password is not set to `null` after each update of the account?

Answer (score 0):

The password is hidden to your frontend. If the frontend sends a request to the backend the password field is not given. There is an easy way to fix it. Before you save the updated entity to your DB, make a request to your Database to retrieve the full object (The best would be using the ID of the Entity). Update that object with the fields which changed, the password field is given there. Save that updated object to your Database where everything is given.

Comment: This is what I am doing now, is there a right way of doing so?

Comment: From my point the right way is to make a request to the DB repository with the ID of the entity if the enpoint is called. The result object can then be changed with the object (DTO) received by the controller. The changed object can then be saved. It contains all values.